# Vietnam from middle of August for a month?

Tags: weather-and-climate, southeast-asia, vietnam

I'm going on a 3 month trip starting with Vietnam in the middle of August. I'll be in Vietnam for about 1 month before moving on to Cambodia.

I've read up on where to go in Vietnam and thought I'd either fly in to Hanoi and make my way south or fly to Saigon and just stay in the southern part of Vietnam. While reading I came across some information that during the period I'll be there the weather will be really bad in the north (like typhoons raging unpredictably and violently a lot of the time).

So my question is, would I be better of just staying in the south or is the information I have exaggerated?

Comment: Hey @Asparatame, your question - while well written, is a bit subjective - when you ask - would you be better off - are you prepared to deal with bad weather or not? If you're after the sun and sand, for example, the answer would differ to if you were prepared to be indoors looking at culture or learning the language.  If you could clarify that, I'm happy to chuck a bounty on to help get this answered for you!

Comment: No response from OP, so I'm closing this, but happy to reopen if edited and flagged by @Asparatame.